# Example code for a simple web page browser using WebKit QT in C++

Tags: c++, qt, webkit, qt4, qtwebkit

I have never used `Qt` and `WebKit` and now have a need to create a simple single web page browser using the `Qt WebKit module`. The application that I'm looking to create needs to have a plain window that displays a web page URL passed in via command line. I've done this sort of thing using `WebKitGTK` but I have no idea where to start in `Qt`.

I've done some research to see what is involved and so far I've only been able to find snippets of code that pertain to the `WebKit` `QWebView` class.

So can anybody provide me with complete sample code that will just display a web page in `Qt`? Once I get that part down I will be able to continue and extend from there and continue to learn about `Qt` and `WebKit`.

I will offer up a great deal of bounty points for some excellent help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your requirement is still not scoped enough. If you want the simplest possible full application example which displays a web page, here is the code:

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtWebKit>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QWebView view;
    view.show();
    view.setUrl(QUrl("http://google.com"));
    return app.exec();
}
```

If that is `example.cpp`, you can use the following `example.pro`:

```
QT += webkit
SOURCES = example.cpp
```

The easiest way to Qt development is using Qt Creator and you can load that .pro file with Qt Creator, build the app, and launch it. There is only one window (`QWebView` instance) and it will open Google homepage.

Comment: Well this works great using QtWebKit-47. However, it doesn't seems to be able to play videos using HTML5 video tags. Any idea what the issue may be? I'm running on CentOS 5.8. Regards.

Comment: Probably codecs issue or some other related stuff. You should post a new question which is more specific and better scoped.

Comment: @AriyaHidayat This doesn't work in Qt 5.9.4 -- is there a change that has happened in Qt?