# Simple WebKit2 example with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, webkit

I'm trying to build a super simple dummy web-view with Qt and WebKit to view pages, so that I can better understand the WebKit2 split process model.

Existing examples/questions (like [Example code for a simple web page browser using WebKit QT in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616342/example-code-for-a-simple-web-page-browser-using-webkit-qt-in-c)) seem to use the "old" style WebKit, in which rendering and displaying are done in one process. What is the equivalent of that example but done for WebKit2?

Is it so difficult with WebKit2 that there aren't any basic examples out there?

Answer (score 2):

Qt's WebKit2 is available only for QML.

> With Qt 5 and Webkit2 the APIs for QtWebKit and Web View are changing significantly. This is because with WebKit2, WebKit and the application run in different processes. The old QWebView widget will only be supported on Qt for desktops and won't use the new WebKit2. Mobile phone platforms typically won't have the QWidgets module installed in Qt 5.

Examples which uses QtWebKit QML API that utilizes the WebKit2 split-process architecture could be found in [Qt WebKit documentation](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qtwebkitexamples-index.html) There is [Flickr View](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qtwebkitexamples-webkitqml-flickrview-example.html) and [YouTube View](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qtwebkitexamples-webkitqml-youtubeview-example.html) examples

Qt also has [WebView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebview-webview.html) module with examples like [Minibrowser](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebview-minibrowser-example.html)

And [WebEngine](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-index.html) module. Examples can be found [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/webengine-examples.html)

And here is a simplest WebKit2 example which just shows google webpage

- Use **Qt 5.5.1** to run this example.
- Add following to your **.pro** file: `QT += quick qml webkit`

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtWebKit 3.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 967
    height: 480

    WebView {
        id: webView
        anchors.fill: parent
        opacity: 0

        url: "https://google.com"

        Behavior on opacity 
        {
            NumberAnimation { duration: 200 }
        }

        onLoadingChanged: 
        {
            switch (loadRequest.status)
            {
            case WebView.LoadSucceededStatus:
                opacity = 1
                break
            default:
                opacity = 0
                break
            }
        }

        onNavigationRequested: 
        {
            request.action = WebView.AcceptRequest
        }
    }    
}
```